# Twig: How to get the last character in a string

Tags: string, twig

I there,

I'm trying to find the last character for a string in twig.
What I need to do is that if the string ends with s then I only add ' Zone and if the string doesn't have an s at the end I should add 's Zone.

E.g., "Charles's Zone" should become "Charles' Zone".

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd definitely put this in a twig extension and us like `{{ input_string|add_zone }}`.

Comment: {{ '12345'|slice(-1) }}

Answer (score 3):

```
{% set test_string = 'asdfs' %}
{% set test_string = test_string ~ (test_string|last == 's' ? "' " : "'s ") ~ "Zone" %}
```

Answer (score 3):

using **last**

---

{{ [1, 2, 3, 4]|last }}

{# outputs 4 #}

---

{{ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }|last }}

{# outputs 4 #}

---

{{ '1234'|last }}

{# outputs 4 #}

---

Answer (score 0):

I figured a workaround:

```
{% set title = user_name ~ "\'s zone" %}
{% set replace_value_var= "s\'s zone" %}
{% set replace_with_value_var = "s\' zone"%}
{% set MyTitle =  title|replace({ (replace_value_var): replace_with_value_var })   %}
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 3, you can use `slice` filter like this:

```
{{ 'Charles\'s'|slice(0, -1) }}

{# outputs Charles' #}
```

or with shorthand notation:

```
{{ 'Charles\'s'[:-1] }}

{# outputs Charles' #}
```

Full Twig docs for `slice`: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html